# Get zsh to report directory to emacs

Tags: zsh, emacs

From the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Terminal-emulator.html)

> Unlike Shell mode, Term mode does not track the current directory by examining your input. But some shells can tell Term what the current directory is. This is done automatically by bash version 1.15 and later.

It seems this is not done by zsh, at least not by default. Is there an option that I can enable or something?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508387/how-can-i-have-term-el-ansi-term-track-directories-if-using-anyhting-other-tha

Comment: @UlrichDangel That doesn't work for me. I get an error msg like `error in process filter: Not a Tramp file name`

Answer (score 3):

After grepping around the bash source, I found this:

```c
static void
send_pwd_to_eterm ()
{
  char *pwd;

  pwd = get_string_value ("PWD");
  if (pwd == 0)
    pwd = get_working_directory ("eterm");
  fprintf (stderr, "\032/%s\n", pwd);
}
```

That's a bit different then what is documented currently in `term.el`. It seems all I need to put in my .zshrc to get this to work is the following:

```sh
if [ -n "$INSIDE_EMACS" ]; then
    chpwd() {
        print -P "\032/$(pwd)"
    }
fi
```